# Coherent information is a lower bound of channel capacity. What about coherent information based on Renyi entropies?

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory, channel-capacity, renyi-entropies, coherent-information

It is known that coherent information defined in terms of von Neumann entropies is a lower bound of quantum channel capacity. If we define coherent information in terms of $\alpha$-Renyi entropies, would it still be a lower bound?

The $\alpha$-Renyi entropy is defined as
$$S_{\alpha}(\rho) =\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log Tr(\rho^{\alpha} ).$$
For $\alpha \rightarrow 1$, we get the limit case $S_{1}(\rho)$, which is the von Neumann entropy.

[Coherent information](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_information) of a quantum channel $\mathcal{N}$ and an input state $\rho$ is defined as
$$Q_{\alpha}(\rho, \mathcal{N}) = S_{\alpha}(\mathcal{N}\rho)  - S_{\alpha}(\rho, \mathcal{N}) \ \ \textrm{with } \alpha=1$$
and it bounds the channel capacity.

Are there any results for $Q_{\alpha}$ with $\alpha >1$? Mostly, I'm interested in the special case $\alpha=2$.

Comment: I am very much familiar with coherent information, but I have not heard about this $\alpha$-Renyi entropy. Could you recommend a good, comprehensive resource to read about this?

Comment: @FDGod The first few sections might be of interest https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0248

Comment: What is $\mathcal{N}$ here?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic, ah sorry. I edited my question to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks, but now I don't know what $S_\alpha(\rho,\mathcal{N})$ means.